# Bokeh multi_line plot not showing

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bokeh

I'm trying to plot a multi_line in Bokeh but for some reason it's not working. 
I've read in a file with pandas:

`roads = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv')`

and the resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
    osm_id  code    fclass           name        ref    oneway  maxspeed    layer   bridge  tunnel               x                                              y
0   4264947 5152    cycleway         NaN         NaN      B        0         0        F        F    [4.9223553, 4.9223667, 4.9223853]                   [52.3654363, 52.3654277, 52.3654169]
1   4270144 5124    pedestrian      Dapperplein  NaN      B        0         0        F        F    [4.9279354, 4.9280225, 4.9280546, 4.928041, 4....   [52.3619809, 52.362025, 52.3621167, 52.3622213...
2   4270151 5153    footway      Zeeburgerstraat NaN      B        0         0        F        F    [4.9261096, 4.9260732, 4.9258198]                   [52.3663263, 52.3662732, 52.3661229]
3   4270806 5152    cycleway      Roomtuintjes   NaN      B        0         0        F        F    [4.9308652, 4.9308238, 4.9307548, 4.9304676, 4...   [52.3659402, 52.3657291, 52.3655389, 52.364919...
4   4277440 5124    pedestrian    Vondelpark     NaN      B        0         0        F        F    [4.881478, 4.8816828, 4.881693]                     [52.361566, 52.361699, 52.3617067]
```

When I try to plot the coordinates with bokeh

```
source = ColumnDataSource(roads)

q = figure(title= "Roads", plot_width=900, plot_height=900)

q.multi_line('x', 'y', source = source, color='blue', line_width=0.5)

show(q)
```

It outputs an empty plot.

[image: emptyplot]

What is going wrong and is there someone that can help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is list in columns, here string repr of list. So first are converted both columns to lists::

```
import ast

roads = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv')

roads['x'] = roads['x'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
roads['y'] = roads['y'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Another solution:

```
import ast

conv = lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x)
roads = pd.read_csv('path/file.csv', converters={'x':conv, 'y':conv})
```

---

```
source = ColumnDataSource(roads)

q = figure(title= "Roads", plot_width=900, plot_height=900)

q.multi_line('x', 'y', source = source, color='blue', line_width=0.5)

show(q)
```

Comment: When using  ```roads['x'] = roads['x'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
roads['y'] = roads['y'].apply(ast.literal_eval)```

The code works fine when using ```roads``` as ```ColumnDataSource``` I'm not sure I understand the need to concatenate it to a separate dataframe

Comment: @borisvanax - You are right, then solution is simplier